# Make a transparent inner div non-opaque through an opaque parent

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to have a transparent div that has an opacity of 1 inside a parent div that has an opacity of 0.2 such that the body color blue is not opaque out within the "rect" div class. I have provided an example of how I wish the DOM to be. Is this possible without modify the DOM in any way?

Best Regards,
J

http://jsfiddle.net/eb1ew9mt/2/

```
body {
    background:blue;
}
.mybody {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    z-index:-1;
}

.rect {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:transparent;
    z-index:999;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you want here. Are you saying you want to see the body background colour show through in `.rect`? Could you perhaps mock up some screens?

Comment: Hi yes: I want it to look like this:

Except i dont want .rect to have a background-color:blue. I want it to have a background-color:transparent;
MOCK:
http://jsfiddle.net/eb1ew9mt/6/

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that with CSS

Comment: check this then http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

http://jsfiddle.net/eb1ew9mt/1/

All you have to do is make the inner element absolutely positioned compared to the relative parent.

```
body {
    background:blue;
}
.mybody {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position:relative;
}

.rect {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: The position property [has no effect](http://jsfiddle.net/eb1ew9mt/11/) on background opacity.